# Bun js SegmentationFault at 188

Tags: javascript, npm, npm-install, yarn-lock.json, bun

I am trying to run below command on my existing repo which has registry setup in the `.npmrc`

`bun install -y`

The `-y` flag is for generating yarn v1 lockfile

It result into following error:

`SegmentationFault at 188`

How to setup the .rc file for bun to pickup?

Comment: have you checked bun github for issues ... like https://github.com/oven-sh/bun/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+188

Comment: yes, no mention about reading registry file

Comment: What were the causes of the reported issues? What makes you think `error: SegmentationFault at 188` has anything to do with "reading registry file"?

Comment: My project references to private npm registry (behind a proxy)

Comment: Very interesting - in the issues that you just read, what was the cause of `SegmentationFault at 188` - hint: one person said something about a proxy! Seems `bun` is too immature to handle anything but direct connections

Comment: https://github.com/oven-sh/bun/issues/565 - looks like someone is working on the issue of adding packages behind a proxy - the solution now is to *wait*, as this issue was raised a day ago

Comment: From what I can gather, isn't Bun `node_modules` resolution compatible with NPM, if so could you just use NPM / PNPM for now until it's fixed.   I was thinking of giving Bun a try, but not having symlinked node_modules like PNPM, and workspace not yet done.  I was thinking of just using PNPM & Bun together..

Comment: I have the exact same issue and I am indeed behind a proxy. It may also be related to SSL/TLS misconfiguration.
```
GET /@types/serve-index
 [0m[36mIf-None-Match[0m[2m: [0m"9ad5f009b7a096fe1e7f7a00d74863b0"
 [0m[36mAccept[0m[2m: [0mapplication/vnd.npm.install-v1+json; q=1.0, application/json; q=0.8, */*
 [0m[36mConnection[0m[2m: [0mclose
 [0m[36mUser-Agent[0m[2m: [0mbun.js 0.1.4
 [0m[36mHost[0m[2m: [0mregistry.npmjs.org
 [0m[36mAccept-Encoding[0m[2m: [0mdeflate, gzip
SegmentationFault at 188
```

Answer (score 1):

Bun is still in alpha. Bugs like this would happen. Solution is to use another runtime like Nodejs, or Deno; or just wait for devs to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

There is no .rc file for bun instead you can use **bunfig.toml** file to specify your package registry.

This is **.npmrc** file

```
    @myorg:registry=https://github.com//projects/34234/packages/npm/
    
   //https://github.com//projects/34234/packages/npm/:_authToken=j34j3543j53
```

And this is how your **bunfig.toml** will look like

```
[install.scopes]
"@myorg" = { token = "j34j3543j53", url = "https://github.com//projects/34234/packages/npm/" }
```